# URL parameter to force user to stay in Classic/Aloha UI?

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience

I'm building an app which is currently 100% lightning UX, however I have a link to a standard report which I would like to force the user to stay in the Classic/Aloha UX to view. When navigating to the report URL, it is presented in the lightning style.

Is there a URL parameter which will force the report page to load in the Aloha style?

I am looking for a parameter that is similar in functionality to the `nooverride` and `isdtp` parameters.

Comment: did you try putting with the full report url in the link as appeared on classic?

Comment: man i would love to have this so that i can send users back to classic for key items that aren't yet possible in lex

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't believe this is possible.  What is the reason for wanting to use classic? If it is simply that you need parameter values this is now supported in Winter '17.

You can force both classic and Lightning to use lightning for the report by making a link as follows:

/one/one.app?source=aloha#/sObject/[reportId]/view?fv0={!Object__c.field}

where [reportId] is the Id of the report and fv0 is the first parameter (equivalent to pv in classic) and {!Object__c.field} is the field you wish to reference in your button/link

Comment: A side note: The parameters do not currently work on mobile browsers or salesforce1

Comment: Do you have a link to any documentation that shows this becoming a supported method of passing params to a report starting in Winter 17?

Comment: Sorry, that is a typo - it is actually spring '17, not Winter. Here is the documentation: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_rd_reports_filter_url.htm